# Edit rejected twice as minor edits

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, too-minor

Twice today my edits have been rejected by [minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech).

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2978871
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2978811

The chosen reason was

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

After which he made the same edits on the post with little difference.

Are these edits I made really minor? And if so, what was I wrong to have edited it?

Comment: I would have rejected them as well. You made a good attempt but changing "plz" to "pls" is, in my book, an instant reject (I'll normally edit and say yours wasn't helpful rather than actually rejecting).

Comment: I'm not sure I would have gone for "too minor". I would certainly have improved them. I might have rejected the second one. Editing in "Can anyone pls help me." is a no no. Pls is not a word.

Comment: A `?` instead of a `.` would've been better, too.  But I'm sure you get the point now.

Comment: FWIW, I would have accepted the first one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both times, you formatted code, and left enormous, inconsistent leading indentation, as well as introducing a

> Can anyone pls help me.

in the second. Too minor.

Comment: `Can anyone pls help me.` Alright now lets say I did that the first time so what did I do the second time????

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi: Read the “both times” at the beginning of my answer

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi Please note it is "I", not "i".

Comment: @Bart Does it really matter??

Comment: Yes it does. It really matters a whole lot, because "i" is simply wrong.

Comment: @Bart Ok. Learnt something today lol

Comment: @minitech Ok. Realised my mistake. I'll take note next time

Answer (score 7):

People with enough rep to just edit themselves are welcome to make tiny edits if they feel like it. On the other hand, people without enough rep to just edit are not supposed to clog the edit queue with tiny edits. Aside from the points about substance raised in the comments, there's nothing very wrong with the pattern in which someone rejects an edit as 'too small' and then turns around and makes the same change themselves as part of an edit. They aren't consuming reviewer attention.

Comment: And that's exactly why I *always* go all-out when I suggest an edit.  The only thing that bothers me a bit is when a direct edit still leaves a number of minor things (mostly grammar), but suggesting edits on them wouldn't be enough to warrant approval.  In those cases, I just go about my business.